# How to run docker containers as a non-root user in Amazon ECS on Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-fargate

A non-root user can run docker containers by using USER instruction.
reference: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#user

I want to do that in Amazon ECS on Fargate.

How does a non-root user run docker containers in Amazon ECS on Fargate?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you happen to manage the Dockerfile, you may just include the `USER` directive to it to prevent the resulting container from running as root. You may also create an ad-hoc Dockerfile with the `FROM` instruction pointing to the image you want to run as non-root, and the `USER` directive. All these require using a Dockerfile and building the image on your own.

The other alternatives are removing the shell, which is something you could do after the container starts using `rm`, but this is a very basic mitigation that won't prevent from accessing sensible data in the container.

Finally, if using Kubernetes there is a policy to run as user or group. I will directly paste the fragment of my source for this answer: [AWS - EKS Best Practices  Guide](https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/pods/#do-not-run-processes-in-containers-as-root)

> The Kubernetes podSpec includes a set of fields under `spec.securityContext`, that allow to let you specify the user and/or group to run your application as. These fields are `runAsUser` and `runAsGroup` respectively. You can mandate the use of these fields by creating a pod security policy. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#users-and-groups for further information on this topic.

Comment: The question is about running Docker image in Amazon ECS on Fargate.

Answer (score 3):

When running container images in Amazon ECS as Fargate tasks, there are the parameters "user", "privileged" as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html which could be used to specify the user to use for running the container.

Comment: Note that the `privileged` parameter cannot be used with Fargate.